# UX Studio Server connection not established

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Today I got the update for UX Studio Plugin and after installing it I'm not able to upload a code using UX Studio.
I have re-installed the eclipse and UX studio plugin several times but it won't work for me.

Facing the same error :
***Unable to connect to the Digital Server. Use the 'Back' button to check your User credentials and then try again.***

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
[Error]

Answer (score 3):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Network Connections
Set active provider drop down value to direct.
Try creating a digital connection now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent unfixed error with respect to the latest version(20.xx) of the UX studio plugin. You can try the following approaches

1. Installing previous Eclipse versions: We use http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.6 for installing UX studio plugin. This link will automatically install latest 20.xx version of UX plugin in latest Eclipse versions. So to avoid that, you can try installing older versions like Neon/Oxygen and try installing UX studio(check if it's version is 19.xx) I tried this approach and it worked for me. Hopefully it works for you too :)
2. TrailHead Solution: I came across this solution in [TrailHead Known issues](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000wqSyQAI&title=issues-while-uploading-code-using-uxstudio-20-10) regarding the same topic. You can verify this too.

Do let me know if either of them works for you.